# Adding data to sqlite via core data - can add to one table but not the other

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm trying to add data onto a User table and a Items table. Adding to the User is fine, but somehow it doesn't add to the items table

there are no errors for both.

E.g. when I `NSFetchRequest` on Items, straight after I add to the table, I can see the data. But after I re-built and run the app again. Its gone but the User records are still there.

How come?

And also, I checked manually the sqlite database. User records exist but not the Items.

Comment: Core Data can be backed by a sqlite store, but is not a database.  Thus, from the level of abstraction that Core Data offers, the term 'table' is not applicable.  We really need to see your code to offer much advice - mainly how you are adding managed objects to the persistent store and how you're saving the managed object context.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example

I have a Create Account viewController

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(BDOAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    User *newUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    newUser.firstName = firstName;
    newUser.lastName = lastName;
    newUser.emailAddress = email;
    newUser.password = password;
```

This part is fine. It actually does add to the User model.

I also store the log in and log out times for the Users in another view controller

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(BDOAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

```
- (void)signLoggedInLoggedOut:(User *)getUser:(NSNumber *)login
{    
    LoggedInLoggedOut *newRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LoggedInLoggedOut" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    newRecord.user = getUser;
    newRecord.login = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    //input the time (NSDATE) as well
    newRecord.created_at = [NSDate date];
    //Create relationship with User - LoggedInLoggedOut
    [getUser addLoggedInLoggedOutsObject:newRecord];
}
```

So the relationship is 1-to-many i.e. User can have multiple login logout entries.

When I fetch it instantly, the I can actually retrieve the data.

But when I quit, build then run again. The login and logout data is not stored. But the User is actually stored.

So I dunno how to fix this